# How can I track AdWords conversions using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api

I need to execute Google AdWords conversion code but I have constraints...

Here are the given circumstances:

1) I cannot redirect to another page to allow the conversion code to run. (client request)

2) I cannot add an onClick function to my submit button because it is not directly editable. (plugin restraint, I'm using a WordPress plugin called "Easy Contact Forms")

How do I turn this AdWords code into an executable Javascript chunk that will function when a user clicks submit on the form:

```
<!-- Google Code for sent email Conversion Page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = XXXXXXXXX;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "2";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
var google_conversion_value = 0;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/XXXXXXXXX/?value=0&amp;label=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
```

And here is the chunk of code that contains the form area that includes the submit button:

```
<span id="ufo-field-id-630-span">
<noscript><button type='submit' id='ufo-field-id-630' name='id-630' >Send Message</button></noscript>
<button class="" type="button" style="">Send Message</button>
</span>
```

Now remember I am not able to edit this area of the plugin because of the way the plugin is coded. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I also want to forewarn you that I know very little about JavaScript so if possible could you please go easy on me with a solution?

Thanks in advance!
Patrick

Answer (score 1):

Look my answer here [How to execute Google Adwords conversion tracking without physical thank you page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087636/how-to-execute-google-adwords-conversion-tracking-without-physical-thank-you-pag/19766470#19766470), in another stackoverflow discussion. It looks like, that it is the same question as yours.